# "encrypted" answer: Troll, "not an answer" or just "not useful"?

Tags: discussion

I have troubles deciding what to do with this answer:

> Qwerty ah cm lv sb mx an Decode it to get answer

*(I could of course link, but I don't want to witch-hunt, just help with deciding. Let me know if a link here is appropriate.)*

My suspicion is that it is simply a troll, to be downvoted and ignored; because the text is not a cypher for anything or at least too short to contain anything useful.
That would be assuming that I am intelligent enough to find the used cypher if any.
But what if the user actually intended to be helpful and there IS a useful, though extremely short answer?
Asking a troll what the idea of his post is (or to decypher it) would be the wrong thing to do.

So I looked for an applicable flag, daring to make a fool of myself for not underrstanding the cypher. But (with the fear of a genius cyphered answer..) I couldn't bring myself to flag "rude", "naa", "low quality".

I had a comment "That answer is wrong." for a few minutes, hoping to provoke a reaction which would allow to decide. But I realised it potentially was just troll-feeding.

So, any proposals on how to react?

Comment: In case people go looking: I deleted it already. In future, feel free time use a custom moderator flag and explain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (and the people agreeing with the comment) Thanks. Early in my StackOverflow life, I got a (very appropriatly and politely phrased) "Do not waste moderators time." answer on a moderator flag. So I became very careful with that. With your recommendation, I will consider moderator flags more openly again. A little more openly, don't worry.

Comment: Now I'm curious what it says.

Comment: I still think there is nothing meaningful encrypted in the "answer". But some comments and answer sound like the authours think there is. If it is just me being blind, please enlighten me.

Comment: I would like to accept an answer to select the moderator flag option (matching the comment by @MartijnPieters). I myself won't make and accept that answer and I respect all non-moderators who don't either. Would a diamond be so kind to make that answer? That would seem appropriate to me.

Comment: This is probably an entirely different question, but would there *ever* be a reasonable use case for "spoiler" tags on Stack Overflow similar to Arquade and other Stack Exchange sites, such as: "Here are the broad steps to solve your problem, I'm spoiling the exact steps to give you a chance to figure it out"?

Comment: @zero298 I don't think so, that's not really the point of Stack Overflow.  The only case I can think of where you wouldn't want to give a direct answer is when you suspect they're cheating on their homework or something, in which case you should probably just not answer at all.

Comment: @Yunnosch in the future if you want to select information from a comment/etc as an answer without getting rep points yourself for it, just post a community wiki answer quoting the comment in question.

Comment: @zero298 stackoverflow is not a homework help site, those of us who're long term members here may remember The Great Homework Tag Nuking of 2012 where ~20k questions were reviewed and either cleaned up or deleted.

Comment: @DanNeely You did not get my point. It is not about the rep (which I think answering on meta does not yield anyway; at least a upvoted question does not give any). It is about a statement which I would not find appropriate from a non-diamond, even if quoted from a comment.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think the description on the Very Low Quality flag applies:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Unless you think it's possible to salvage it by editing, which it appears intentionally designed not to be.

Comment: +1 I'd consider deliberate obfuscation to be a "severe formatting" problem.

Comment: unless the act of decrypting it somehow is the answer to the question

Comment: I like the idea that intentionally making an answer unreadable is considered a "severe formatting problem". I will consider the outcome (votes on my question and on this answer) to be a clear signal that it can be considered an accepted rule on StackOverflow. For the special case of encrypted answer it is therefor what helped me most, so I accept.