# Is there an issue with the spam reporting workflow on deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, spam, moderation

I recently reported [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234591/472495) (10K only) for being an obvious spammer. I seem to recall I saw this in SO CVR, but by the time I got to it, the question was deleted by its author. The spam answer was:

> DQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKUDQWSWFETGRETRJYKU

(There's an outside possibility that a reasonable answer was given, and then it was vandalised during the grace period for editing, but given the answer author has no other material, I think it would be better to report it than not to).

It turns out that on deleted answers (or, perhaps, answers on deleted questions) the only flagging option available is this:

> [*] in need of moderator intervention
>
> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

So I added a custom message thus:

> Worth deleting this user as a potential spammer? – halfer 2 days ago

In reply I received this from a moderator, and I can't tell if it is merely pasted boilerplate or written with a measure of exasperation:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

There seems to be an issue here. Perhaps one of these applies?

- I should be able to alert moderators to potential spam in an answer even if the question is deleted, using a specific "spam" designation
- If the reply from a moderator was boilerplate, and if the moderation UI can allow or disallow certain boilerplate messages to be sent, then perhaps it should not offer it as an option where the question is deleted (since it makes no sense to require a spam designation from ordinary users where the flagging UI does not allow it)
- Moderators just need to check whether the question is deleted (and also need to remember that asking for spam designations is not possible on such questions). I dislike this the least since I think mods are overburdened as it is, and I'd rather the UI guided them a bit more.

Comment: That's not spam. [Spam is an unsolicited commercial advertisement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2675154). It's rather abusive (flag "rude or abusive").

Comment: @honk: ah, thanks. I'd have thought it would be best to treat it as spam, since accounts that post nonsense are routinely deleted, but I imagine the bar is very high to delete it if it is merely "rude or abusive".

Comment: Nevertheless, there's still a problem here, since I am being directed to "[use] standard flags" and a standard flag was not available. I used the _only_ flag type that was available. Indeed, if the content of the answer _was_ UCE, it should still be reportable as such, even if it is deleted.

Comment: As far as I remember, several "rude or abusive" flags also have a negative impact on the receiver's account. And normally "rude or abusive" is always directly below the "spam" flag. Maybe the post got handled the moment before you opened the flag dialog and therefore the options were reduced?

Comment: That post certainly [is red flaggable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310177/is-a-post-like-assdddsssafffwq-spam), use spam/rude (red) flag. I did not handle your flag there, but it seems like the mod who did got a bit confused with your flag text, but to me it seems quite clear that you wanted the user to be deleted. I have nuked the user now.

Comment: If I use a custom mod flag I include why I didn't/couldn't use any of the default moderation options at my disposal. *The post is already spam-deleted but I have reason to believe this user account only exists for posting spam. Can you use your tools to investigate if extra actions are warranted*.  The moderator feels this as very welcoming and your flag gets marked helpful.

Comment: @rene: I see what you did there ;)

Comment: @rene: ha, cheeky `;-)`

Comment: I sooo want to add a random character answer to this question.

Comment: Looks similar to what I discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365350/encrypted-answer-troll-not-an-answer-or-just-not-useful

Comment: @honk Certainly, that text doesn't qualify as spam. However, it _could_ be a spam precursor: random text that doesn't contain any obvious spam keywords gets posted & if it survives long enough then the author replaces it with the actual commercial spam payload and undeletes the answer. Of course, that technique is useless if the answer is on a deleted question.

Answer (score 8):

I declined it and yes a custom message would have been better. Honestly that is my fault for not taking the time to explain the decline.

That decline message is one of the templates from a script that many mods use, as the boiler plate reasons are limited. I've added a few more templates to my own browser.

The reason I declined it, was because it was a harmless post that was deleted quickly and there's been incidents of people testing the UI with posts like that (they obviously don't realise it trips flags etc and stays on the site).

Comment: I'll try to find the reference to people testing the UI

Comment: Alright, thanks Yvette, and no worries. From your perspective, is there a reason why the "spam" radio button in the flag dialogue is missing? It seems to me that if a question is deleted and it carries an answer with it, then the answer itself has not been deleted, and if it is spam (however that is defined) then we'd want a way to handle it.

Comment: (From Honk's suggestion, I'll not treat nonsense posts as spam in the future, but nevertheless real spam could still appear in this kind of scenario.)

Comment: @halfer if a question has been deleted and the answer is still there, it will be automatically deleted within 24 hours. It's a glitch. I don't know about the missing radio button. Search and ask?

Comment: How is "*because it was a harmless post*" and "*people testing the UI with posts like that*" relevant? Does amount of "harm" (and perceived behavioral trends) keep garbage from being considered spam?

Comment: @user4157124 There is a big difference between garbage and spam. Sure, many people use the term "spam" to refer to any unwanted / useless content, but the Stack Exchange spam flag is _only_ for commercial spam. Posting actual commercial spam leads to heavy penalties, mere garbage doesn't. However see [my previous comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370821/is-there-an-issue-with-the-spam-reporting-workflow-on-deleted-questions#comment608620_370821).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for explaining. To distinguish from popular use less ambiguous naming would be welcome (advertising, promotion or commercial intent for example).

Comment: @user4157124 there's a lot of semantics, which makes it difficult

Comment: Perhaps the popup should have a link to [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?
](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor), if that's technically feasible.

Comment: @user4157124 Fair point, although that more general usage of "spam" is relatively recent compared to the earlier meaning that was restricted to stuff posted for commercial advantage. Also, as Yvette says, it's difficult to give a concise clear-cut definition.

Comment: The flag popup already describes "spam" as "Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)." That seems pretty clear.